# Как менять высоту элемента снизу вверх

Tags: html, css

Как сделать такое поведение элемента?

Начальное положение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конечное положение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При `height: 100%;` высота меняется сверху вниз, а как это сделать наоборот?

Comment: Высота и должна меняться сверху вниз, в css координаты начинаются с слева и сверху

Comment: Предоставьте код для воспроизведения вашей ситуации, чтобы мы могли вам помочь. Здесь я вижу два варианта решения задачи, 1ое - использовать псевдоэлемент в качестве оранжевого объекта, 2ое - использовать флекс и трансформировать сам объект.

Comment: Возможно, вас интересует, как переместить стрелку в левый нижний угол, в таком случае стоит переформулировать вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #091219;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.button::before {
  content: "";
  background: url("http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/up_direction.png") no-repeat left 3px bottom 3px #f04e1d;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transition: width 0.5s ease, height 0.5s ease;
}

.button:hover::before {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="button"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container-black-padding-20px {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-black {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  color: black;
  --width: 80px;
  --height: 40px;
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  padding: calc(var(--height) / 3.5) calc(var(--width) / 6);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-end;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: width, height;
}

.btn:hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-black-padding-20px">
  <div class="container-black">
    <div class="btn">
      Кнопка
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```